# Problems with CIFS and fstab

Tags: samba, fstab, cifs

Something altered my `fstab` and my NAS drives stopped loading properly at startup or when I run `mount -a`. I see:

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
```

I'm running 12.04. Here's what I in my `fstab`:

```
//192.168.0.40/Data  /media/NAS-Data  cifs  credentials=/etc/nas.txt  0 0
```

1. I can verify that my credentials are where they've always been (nothing changed there)
2. I have `cifs-utils` and `smbfs` installed
3. I'd previously had the drives mounting via SMBFS but changed the `fstab` line to `cifs`

Comment: Did to mount manually? `sudo mount.cifs //192.168.0.40/Data /media/NAS-Data -o credentials=/etc/nas.txt`.

Comment: I mean: Did you try to mount it manually?

Comment: Same error when done manually via the above.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like the permissions on the remote machine's shared directory somehow changed. Or the remote machine's credentials changed.

Is this DHCP?  I've had it happen that the machine changed IP and a new machine took the old IP and then kicked you out because you didn't have the permission, when really it was just telling you "Hey, it's the other dude, Jim, not Pete."

Your credential file is probably fine, just like you say.

Have you done any updates recently?